# Parsing if-else if statement algorithm

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying to create a very simple parser for an if-else type structure that will build and execute a SQL statement.

Rather than testing conditions for executing statements, I would be testing conditions to build a string.

An example of a statment would be:

```
select column1
from
#if(VariableA = Case1)
table1
#else if(VariableA = Case2)
table2
#else
defaultTable
#end
```

If VariableA equals Case1 the resulting string should be: `select column1 from table1`

A more complex example would be with nested if statements:

```
select column1
from
#if(VariableA = Case1)
#if(VariableB = Case3)
    table3
#else
    table4
#else if(VariableA = Case2)
table2
#else
defaultTable
#end
```

This is where I am really having trouble, I can't think of a good way to identify each if-else-end group correctly.

Also, I'm not sure what a good way to keep track of if the string in the "else" clause should evaluate to true.

I have been looking around the net at different types of parsing algorithms, all of them seeming very abstract and complex.

Are there any suggestions of a good place to start for this non-computer science major?

Comment: Wait, are you parsing a string or building a string?

Comment: I am parsing a string AND building a string. The output of the parsing will be a new string that contains the desired pieces of the SQL query.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are creating a language of your own and don't use already existing language, like C#?

Comment: Also, if you're building your own language and a parser for it, you should know at least the basics of the theory about grammars and formal languages.

Comment: Yes - this is for a reporting application that is designed to be entirely dynamic. I don't want to re-write and re-deploy my application every time I write a new report.

Comment: @svick - Constructive comments would be appreciated. I only want to have the ability to conditionally build SQL strings based on simple expression evaluation, not develop a complex new language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a simple parser, which I tested against the example you provided. If you want to know more about parsing I suggest you to read [Compiler Construction](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/CompilerConstruction/index.html) from Niklaus Wirth.

The first step is always to write down the syntax of your language in an appropriate way. I have chosen EBNF, which is very simple to understand.

`|` separates alternatives.

`[` and `]` enclose options.

`{` and `}` denote repetitions (zero, one or more).

`(` and `)` group expressions (not used here).

This description is not complete but the link I provided describes it in more detail.

The EBNF syntax

```
LineSequence = { TextLine | IfStatement }.
TextLine     = <string>.
IfStatement  = IfLine LineSequence { ElseIfLine LineSequence } [ ElseLine LineSequence ] EndLine.
IfLine       = "#if" "(" Condition ")".
ElseLine     = "#else".
ElseIfLine   = "#else" "if" "(" Condition ")".
EndLine      = "#end".
Condition    = Identifier "=" Identifier.
Identifier   = <letter_or_underline> { <letter_or_underline> | <digit> }.
```

The parser follows closely the syntax, i.e. a repetition is translated into a loop, an alternative into an if-else statement, and so on. The syntax elements (productions) are realized by methods that can be called recursively. This reflects the recursive nature of the syntax. E.g., an `IfStatement` can contain yet another `IfStatement` in one if its branches.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Example.SqlPreprocessor;

class Parser
{
    enum Symbol
    {
        None,
        LPar,
        RPar,
        Equals,
        Text,
        NumberIf,
        If,
        NumberElse,
        NumberEnd,
        Identifier
    }

    List<string> _input; // Raw SQL with preprocessor directives.
    int _currentLineIndex = 0;

    // Simulates variables used in conditions
    readonly Dictionary<string, string> _variableValues = new() {
                { "VariableA", "Case1" },
                { "VariableB", "CaseX" }
            };

    Symbol _sy; // Current symbol.
    string _string; // Identifier or text line;
    readonly Queue<string> _textQueue = new(); // Buffered text parts of a single line.
    int _lineNo; // Current line number for error messages.
    string _line; // Current line for error messages.

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the next line from the input.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Input line or null if no more lines are available.</returns>
    string GetLine()
    {
        if (_currentLineIndex >= _input.Count) {
            return null;
        }
        _line = _input[_currentLineIndex++];
        _lineNo = _currentLineIndex;
        return _line;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the next symbol from the input stream and stores it in _sy.
    /// </summary>
    void GetSy()
    {
        string s;
        if (_textQueue.Count > 0) { // Buffered text parts available, use one from these.
            s = _textQueue.Dequeue();
            switch (s.ToLower()) {
                case "(":
                    _sy = Symbol.LPar;
                    break;
                case ")":
                    _sy = Symbol.RPar;
                    break;
                case "=":
                    _sy = Symbol.Equals;
                    break;
                case "if":
                    _sy = Symbol.If;
                    break;
                default:
                    _sy = Symbol.Identifier;
                    _string = s;
                    break;
            }
            return;
        }

        // Get next line from input.
        s = GetLine();
        if (s == null) {
            _sy = Symbol.None;
            return;
        }

        s = s.Trim(' ', '\t');
        if (s[0] == '#') { // We have a preprocessor directive.
                           // Split the line in order to be able get its symbols.
            string[] parts = Regex.Split(s, @"\b|[^#_a-zA-Z0-9()=]");
            // parts[0] = #
            // parts[1] = if, else, end
            switch (parts[1].ToLower()) {
                case "if":
                    _sy = Symbol.NumberIf;
                    break;
                case "else":
                    _sy = Symbol.NumberElse;
                    break;
                case "end":
                    _sy = Symbol.NumberEnd;
                    break;
                default:
                    Error("Invalid symbol #{0}", parts[1]);
                    break;
            }

            // Store the remaining parts for later.
            for (int i = 2; i < parts.Length; i++) {
                string part = parts[i].Trim(' ', '\t');
                if (part != "") {
                    _textQueue.Enqueue(part);
                }
            }
        } else { // We have an ordinary SQL text line.
            _sy = Symbol.Text;
            _string = s;
        }
    }

    void Error(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        // Make sure parsing stops here
        _sy = Symbol.None;
        _textQueue.Clear();
        _input.Clear();

        message = String.Format(message, args) + $" in line {_lineNo}\r\n\r\n{_line}";
        Output("------");
        Output(message);
        Console.WriteLine("!!! Error: " + message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the processed line to a (simulated) output stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line">Line to be written to output</param>
    static void Output(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the parsing process.
    /// </summary>
    public void Parse()
    {
        // Simulate an input stream.
        _input = [
                    "select column1",
                    "from",
                    "#if(VariableA = Case1)",
                    "    #if(VariableB = Case3)",
                    "        table3",
                    "    #else",
                    "        table4",
                    "    #end",
                    "#else if(VariableA = Case2)",
                    "    table2",
                    "#else",
                    "    defaultTable",
                    "#end"
                ];

        // Clear previous parsing
        _textQueue.Clear();
        _currentLineIndex = 0;

        // Get first symbol and start parsing
        GetSy();
        if (LineSequence(true)) { // Finished parsing successfully.
                                  //TODO: Do something with the generated SQL
        } else { // Error encountered.
            Output("*** ABORTED ***");
        }
    }

    // The following methods parse according the the EBNF syntax.

    bool LineSequence(bool writeOutput)
    {
        // EBNF:  LineSequence = { TextLine | IfStatement }.
        while (_sy is Symbol.Text or Symbol.NumberIf) {
            if (_sy == Symbol.Text) {
                if (!TextLine(writeOutput)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else { // _sy == Symbol.NumberIf
                if (!IfStatement(writeOutput)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool TextLine(bool writeOutput)
    {
        // EBNF:  TextLine = <string>.
        if (writeOutput) {
            Output(_string);
        }
        GetSy();
        return true;
    }

    bool IfStatement(bool writeOutput)
    {
        // EBNF:  IfStatement = IfLine LineSequence { ElseIfLine LineSequence } [ ElseLine LineSequence ] EndLine.
        if (IfLine(out bool result) && LineSequence(writeOutput && result)) {
            writeOutput &= !result; // Only one section can produce an output.
            while (_sy == Symbol.NumberElse) {
                GetSy();
                if (_sy == Symbol.If) { // We have an #else if
                    if (!ElseIfLine(out result)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!LineSequence(writeOutput && result)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    writeOutput &= !result; // Only one section can produce an output.
                } else { // We have a simple #else
                    if (!LineSequence(writeOutput)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break; // We can have only one #else statement.
                }
            }
            if (_sy != Symbol.NumberEnd) {
                Error("'#end' expected");
                return false;
            }
            GetSy();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool IfLine(out bool result)
    {
        // EBNF:  IfLine = "#if" "(" Condition ")".
        result = false;
        GetSy();
        if (_sy != Symbol.LPar) {
            Error("'(' expected");
            return false;
        }
        GetSy();
        if (!Condition(out result)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (_sy != Symbol.RPar) {
            Error("')' expected");
            return false;
        }
        GetSy();
        return true;
    }

    private bool Condition(out bool result)
    {
        // EBNF:  Condition = Identifier "=" Identifier.
        string variable;
        string expectedValue;

        result = false;
        // Identifier "=" Identifier
        if (_sy != Symbol.Identifier) {
            Error("Identifier expected");
            return false;
        }
        variable = _string; // The first identifier is a variable.
        GetSy();
        if (_sy != Symbol.Equals) {
            Error("'=' expected");
            return false;
        }
        GetSy();
        if (_sy != Symbol.Identifier) {
            Error("Value expected");
            return false;
        }
        expectedValue = _string;  // The second identifier is a value.

        // Search the variable
        if (_variableValues.TryGetValue(variable, out string variableValue)) {
            result = variableValue == expectedValue; // Perform the comparison.
        } else {
            Error("Variable '{0}' not found", variable);
            return false;
        }

        GetSy();
        return true;
    }

    bool ElseIfLine(out bool result)
    {
        // EBNF:  ElseIfLine = "#else" "if" "(" Condition ")".
        result = false;
        GetSy(); // "#else" already processed here, we are only called if the symbol is "if"
        if (_sy != Symbol.LPar) {
            Error("'(' expected");
            return false;
        }
        GetSy();
        if (!Condition(out result)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (_sy != Symbol.RPar) {
            Error("')' expected");
            return false;
        }
        GetSy();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that the nested if-statements are processed automatically in a quite natural way. First, the grammar is expressed recursively. A `LineSequence` can contain `IfStatment`s and `IfStatment`s contain `LineSequence`s. Second, this results in syntax processing methods that call each other in a recursive manner. The nesting of syntax elements is therefore translated into recursive method calls.

Comment: <3 Olivier, thank you very much for such a complete and informative solution!

Comment: This is an old answer and the C# language has evolved since. I just applied some code fixes suggested by C#12 code analyzers.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/):

> Irony is a development kit for implementing languages on .NET
>   platform. Unlike most existing yacc/lex-style solutions Irony does not
>   employ any scanner or parser code generation from grammar
>   specifications written in a specialized meta-language. In Irony the
>   target language grammar is coded directly in c# using operator
>   overloading to express grammar constructs. Irony's scanner and parser
>   modules use the grammar encoded as c# class to control the parsing
>   process. See the expression grammar sample for an example of grammar
>   definition in c# class, and using it in a working parser.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use an existing code generator like ... C# or T4 templates or ASP.NET MVC partial views.

But if you want to do this yourself you need some kind of recursion (or a stack which is equivalent). It could work like this:

```
string BuildCode(string str)
{
 foreach(Match ifMatch in Regex.Matches("#if(?<condition>[^\n\r]*)[\r\n]*(?<body>.*?)#endif)
 {
  var condition = ifMatch.Groups["condition"].Value;
  return EvaluateCondition(condition) ? BuildCode(ifMatch.Value) : null;
 }
}
```

This is pseudo-code. You need to think through this yourself. This also does not support an else branch but you can add that easily.

Here is a new answer: Use the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to compile a C# function. You can use the ful power of C# but have the C# code stored in a database or so. That way you don't have to redeploy.

Comment: The that regex didn't take into account the else statement. If all your conditions have the form x = y, in C# .NET, easier to first use: 
Regex ifElse = new Regex(@"#if\s*[(]\s*(?<var0Name>[^=) ]*)\s*=\s*(?<var0Value>[^)]*)\s*[)](?<onIfStatement>[^#]*)(?<elseIfs>(?:#else if[^#]*)*)(?:#else(?<onElseStatement>[^#]*))?(?:#end)").
Then, process the inside "else ifs" with a similar regex for #else if, and issue one simple .Matches statement - it will return the array of results, where each entry is an array containing the "whole match" and the match groups (i.e. variable, value, etc).