# How to split string with more then one pair of brackets

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

i try to split string like:

```
((12-5=10)&&(5-4>6))
```

to:

- (
- (12-5=10)
- &&
- (5-4>6)
- )

i try to use Regex but the results of the serach relate to one pair of brackets,
and i can't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: As you are obviously trying to parse expressions I would recommend you to use a full-fledged lexer/parser. Check out flex/bison or antlr for generating those based on rules!

Comment: Agreed with @rickythefox, this is a job for a lexer, not a regex. The language you are trying to parse is **non-regular**, hence making regex an inherently bad choice.

Comment: You need a parser. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9286419/880990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could use something like this. As for the the Insert part, I know it's kinda lame :/

```
          string test = "((12-5=10)&&(5-4>6))";
        string[] Arr= test.Split(new string[{"(",")"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string> newArr = new List<string>();
         int h=0;
        foreach (string s in Arr)           
        { 
            if (s != "&&")
                newArr.Add( s.Replace(s, "(" + s + ")"));
            else 
                newArr.Add(s);
            h++;
        }
        newArr.Insert(0, "(");
        newArr.Insert(newArr.Count , ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do it manually, instead of trying to use regex, imagine parsing through the string one character at a time, and recursively splitting at matching braces.

Pseudocode:

```
initialize depth and start to 0
for each character  
  if it is ( increase depth
  if it is ) 
     decrease depth
     if depth is 0
         parse the substring from start to current character
         set start to current character
```

If there is no need to do it manually, then use some external package.

Comment: thanks for replay! But the solution did not give the result I wanted, from this '( {X} + 5 ) + ( {Z} - {X} / ( 7 - 5 ) )' i get this: -({x}+5 - ) - + - ({z}-{X} / (7-5) - )
any ideas?